# Visual Studio: Build in debug when dependencies are compiled for release

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dependencies

Visual Studio 17 and Windows 10 64

Let's say I have written c++ code that uses a 3rd party library like opencv. That library is compiled for release, not debug.
When I try to build the project in debug it fails because VS can't find the debug libraries. But surely there must be some way to be able to debug only *my* code, I don't expect it to debug opencv functions. How?

Comment: Say clearly what "fails", or no one knows what is wrong. Besides, VS has a setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: To work around the issue, I compiled the debugging libraries for openCV. Although it 'works' now, this doesn't really answer my original question.